# Nextcord Display User Avatar

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

```
@client.command()


async def avatar(ctx, *, member : nextcord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author

    memberAvatar = member.avatar_url

    avaEmbed = nextcord.Embed(title = f"{member.name}'s Avatar")
    avaEmbed.set_image(url = memberAvatar)
await ctx.send(embed = avaEmbed)
```

I get an error running this code, here is the problem I am getting:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Member` does not have the attribute `avatar_url` instead, if you look over at [the docs](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#nextcord.User.avatar) you will see that you should use

```
member.avatar.url
```

Note that `avatar` might be None!

Answer (score 1):

It was changed in Discord.py 2.0 (aka what nextcord uses)

its now `member.avatar.url`

Answer (score 0):

In some forks like `Nextcord`,
its

```
member.avatar.url
```

not `member.avatar_url`
Many other things got changed too, so go ahead and read [the docs.](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#nextcord.User.avatar)

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to make it `member.avatar.url` although, if you want it to be the guild avatar(if the member has one) or just a global avatar you can make it `member.display_avatar`